# java if `String` begins with "red" or "blue"

Tags: java, strings

Given a `String`, if the `String` begins with "red" or "blue" return that color `String`, otherwise return the empty `String`

```
public String seeColor(String str) {
  if(str.length() <= 3){
    if(str.equals("red")){
      return "red";
    }
    return "";
  }
  else if(str.substring(0, 3).equals("red")){
    return "red";
  }
  else if(str.substring(0, 4).equals("blue")){
    return "blue";
  }
  return "";
}
```

I really don't like the fact that I'm using same code for "red" twice but I can't get to think out another way. If `str` is equal to 3, I have to make the check for "red", right? 
Example input: "redxx" - output "red", 
"xxred" - output "", 
"blueAvenue" - output "blue"

Comment: You could add all your test conditions to a separate list, and then use 
[startsWith](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why aren't you using [`String.startsWith(prefix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)?  This should be a one-liner.

```
return str.startsWith("red")  ? "red"  :
       str.startsWith("blue") ? "blue" : "";
```

Comment: Lol, because I did not knew that there is such a thing as `String.startsWith`. Sorry I am really new to programming. Next time I'll read first before asking stupid questions :)

Comment: This was not a stupid question. No one expects you to know the entire set of functions in a language at the start. +1 for solving the problem before asking for a better approach.

Comment: @TejasKale, thank you! I think it's better to do your best and if you can - solve the problem even if it's not the best code you've made, AFTER that ask for better solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example using a list to hold your colors, and [Str.startsWith](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    static final List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("red", "blue");

    static public String seeColor(String str) {
        for (String color : colors ) {
            if (str.startsWith(color)) {
                return color;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> testColors = Arrays.asList("redxx", "xxred", "blueAvenue");

        for (String testColor: testColors) {
            System.out.println(testColor + " -> " + seeColor(testColor));
        }
    }
}
```

Note than when checking for multiple colors, you can only return if the `for` loop matches, and keep the empty return after the loop. In addition notice the simple but subtle naming differentiation between `color` and `colors` which makes it easy to distinguish between the list and a single element.

Answer (score 1):

As @200_success said, `String.startsWith` is great and its use simplifies the code down to:

```
return str.startsWith("red") ? "red" : str.startsWith("blue") ? "blue" : "";
```

I used a nested ternary, but it still is very easy to undertand, and I do not fell like bloating this easy function with `if` and `elif` statements.

Comment: @TsenkoAleksiev I suggest you read [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) so that you can fully understand my answer

Comment: @Caridorc I know about ternary...I did not knew about `String.startsWith` :)